# Xamarin.Forms.OxyPlot TapGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, oxyplot

i'd like to add a TapGestureRecognizer to an OxyPlot PlotView. The tap is only recognized when point is outside of the graph area, just on the borders. It is not fired when tapping in the middle of the graph.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following property

`InputTransparent="true"` to the oxyPlot in XAML

From the docs

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether this element should be involved in the user interaction cycle. This is a bindable property.
>   false if the element and its children should receive input; true if neither the element nor its children should receive input and should, instead, pass inputs to the elements that are visually behind the current visual element. Default is false.

Comment: Hi, InputTransparent="true" causes plot to not respond any more also on the borders. As a workaround i'll set it to true and place some control below it to catch gestures. By the way i can't understand why it is not working.